# WSO2 API Manager authorization issue when logging in

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have been experiencing the issue when installing WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0 with analytics and identity server on ubuntu server using `docker-compose`.

I have managed to set up docker containers on UBUNTU 18.04 server, but I am experiencing the issue. I have created roles and users  (apicreator, apipublisher, webuser) with the same permissions as in the self-paced training. Even though users appear in the list of users, I can't login into WSO2 publisher, or devportal.

It gives me below error message:

> Error 403 : Forbidden The server could not verify that you are
>   authorized to access the requested resource.

Please advise.

Comment: Do you have assigned required roles to the user? Please check whether you have assigned **Internal/creator, Internal/publisher** and **Internal/subscriber** roles for the particular users. Because those roles have assigned Login permission and it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have assigned only the roles which you have created to the users, also assign the following internal roles to the respective users as well.

1. apicreator : **Internal/creator**
2. apipublisher: **Internal/publisher**

If web user is the one who creates applications by logging in to the Developer Portal, assign the **Internal/subscriber** role to the user.